# An investigation of Heine´s characterization of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, continuity

This characterization of continuity, for example, for functions $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, can be stated as:

> A function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous at the point $x_0$ if and only if for every sequence $x_k$ that tends to $x_0$ the sequence $f(x_k)$ tends to $f(x_0)$.

I am trying to minimize the assumptions on sequences as much as possible. for example, I think that Heine´s characterization of continuity would be valid if we would phrase it like this:

> A function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous at the point $x_0$ if and only if for *almost all* sequences $x_k$ that tend to $x_0$ the sequences $f(x_k)$ tend to $f(x_0)$.

Now, the meaning of "*almost all*" can, I believe, be somehow given a more precise meaning.

I am not sure would this phrasing be enough to secure continuity:

> A function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is continuous at the point $x_0$ if and only if for all (except maybe countably many) sequences $x_k$ that tend to $x_0$ the sequences $f(x_k)$ tend to $f(x_0)$.

What do you think about this, in the sense of minimization of assumptions? That is, how much can a requirement on all sequences be weakened so as to still have this theorem valid?

**Edit**: To clarify, I mean that if we suppose that continuity is preserved for some space of sequences smaller than the space of all sequences, then we can show that it is preserved for all sequences. But, how "small" is small? Everywhere dense set of sequences?

Comment: @CameronBuie Edited.No apologies needed, it is nice that you understand now.

Answer (score 2):

Your weakening to all but possibly countably-many sequences works just perfectly. To prove it, we need only prove the following

> **Claim:** Suppose $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, and that there is a sequence of points $x_k$ of $\Bbb R$ and a point $x_0\in\Bbb R$ such that $x_k\to x_0$ but $\neg\bigl(f(x_k)\to f(x_0)\bigr).$ Then there are uncounably-many sequences of points $y_k$ of $\Bbb R$ such that $y_k\to x_0$ but $\neg\bigl(f(y_k)\to f(x_0)\bigr).$

The proof is easy: Simply changing $x_1$ to any other point in $\Bbb R$ allows us to construct uncountably-many such sequences--in fact, continuum-many sequences!

Thus, the best we could do is specify that the number of sequences for which the convergence condition may fail must be less than continuum-many. This may actually be equivalent to saying that the number must be at most countably-many, but it is undecidable in basic set theory whether there are cardinalities between $\aleph_0$ (the cardinality of the natural numbers) and $\mathfrak{c}=\mathbf{2}^{\aleph_0}$ (the cardinality of the set of real numbers and of the power set of the natural numbers).

Comment: The sequences $f(x_k)$ always converge to $f(x_0)$ if sequences $x_k$ converge to $x_0$. I think that you did not understand my question, or I posed it in a non-right way?

Comment: What I meant is that we can somehow take a smaller space of sequences, not all the sequences, and then by arguments of denseness and limits show what I intended to show.

Comment: That is, if that is valid for that smaller space of sequences that then it is valid for all sequences.

Comment: It is undecidable, not unprovable, I think.

Comment: Saying that it is "unprovable whether or not P holds" is identical to saying "undecidable whether P holds," but you're right that the latter is more commonly used. Edited.

Comment: No, it is not identical. Think a little about the meaning of undecidability and unprovability and you should notice a difference. I do not know does there exist mathematical statement that is unprovable, but some are undecidable.

Comment: You're right! I'd forgotten what we learned from Godel's Incompleteness Theorems. Given that, you're right that the statements aren't identical. Rather, the latter implies the former, so my previous version of the post was correct, but not as precise as it is now. Thanks for your critiques!

Comment: No problem, if you want further clarifications, we can discuss in some chat-room, to not to gather comments here.